# Bad behavior with strcat

Tags: c, variables, parameters, parameter-passing, strcat

I implemented the following function in order to copy directories.

```
int copy_dir(char *source, char *destination, char *file_name)
{
    DIR *dir_ptr = NULL;
    struct dirent *direntp;
    char temp_dest[strlen(destination)+1];
    char temp_src[strlen(source)+1];
    strcat(destination, "/");
    strcat(source, "/");
    strcpy(temp_dest, destination);
    strcpy(temp_src, source);

    ...

    if( (dir_ptr = opendir(source)) == NULL )
    {
        fprintf(stderr, "Cannot open %s for copying\n", source);
        return ERR_OPEN_DIR;
    }
    else
    {
        while(direntp = readdir(dir_ptr))
        {     
            // File must already be on the USB key
            if(strcmp(direntp->d_name,file_name) == 0)
            {               
                strcat(temp_dest, direntp->d_name);
                printf("after strcat temp_dest=%s\n", temp_dest);         
                strcat(temp_src, direntp->d_name);
                printf("after strcat temp_src=%s\n", temp_src); 
                printf("destination:%s\n",temp_dest);
                copy_files(temp_src, temp_dest); 
            }
        }
    }
    closedir(dir_ptr);
    return 1;
}
```

I would like to understand why the following implemenation

```
strcat(temp_dest, direntp->d_name);
printf("after strcat temp_dest=%s\n", temp_dest);         
strcat(temp_src, direntp->d_name);
printf("after strcat temp_src=%s\n", temp_src); 
printf("destination:%s\n",temp_dest);
copy_files(temp_src,temp_dest);
```

returns :

```
after strcat temp_dest=/tmp/usb/test10
after strcat temp_src=/media/sda1/test10
destination:10
```

Why 10 is returned an not /tmp/usb/test10 thru the last printf ?

Comment: Where is your `temp_dest` declaration and initialization?

Comment: If you don't mind, can you please provide a [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)?

Comment: @Sourav Ghosh - I don't know what is meant by MCVE? you can send the full form?

Comment: Sorry, I edited my first post and include the entire function

Comment: @bhuvanesh there's a link there. For the OP: in this contest, that would mean you provide a minimal program that compiles and executes (i.e., not just the full function, but also a main and header files). That makes it a lot easier for people to try it out themselves and find the mistake.

Comment: Anyway, `temp_dest` simply doesn't have enough space allocated. You allocate just enough space to copy `destination` into `temp_dest`, and then start appending strings to it; there's not enough memory allocated for `temp_dest` those extra strings. Also, use `strncat` instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is your main problem, first you should not modify `char *source` and `char *destination` because you don't know if there is enough space allocated to append a character, and `strcat` does not allocate it for you, but the most important mistake is this

First you declare these arrays to hold `strlen(string) + 1` characters, which actually means yo can only copy the same string into them, since you need one extra character for the terminating `'\0'` byte which is not counted by `strlen`

```
char temp_dest[strlen(destination)+1];
char temp_src[strlen(source)+1];
```

then you append one more character to the string, this one was not counted by `strlen`, so now the string wont fit your array, and also, you don't know if `destination` and `source` have enough space for one more character.

```
strcat(destination, "/");
strcat(source, "/");
```

and finally you copy the string

```
strcpy(temp_dest, destination);
strcpy(temp_src, source);
```

I suggest you do it this way

```
size_t dest_length = strlen(destination);
size_t src_length = strlen(source);
char temp_dest[dest_length+2];
char temp_src[scr_length+2];

temp_dest[dest_length] = '/';
temp_src[src_length] = '/';
temp_dest[1 + dest_length] = '\0';
temp_src[1 + src_length] = '\0';

memcpy(temp_dest, destination, dest_length);
memcpy(temp_src, source, src_length);
```